# Leaflet causing an error in with R Markdown

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown

When I try to use R Markdown (in R Studio) along with Leaflet I get an error and it fails. Here is a simple R Markdown script along with the error I am getting. I have tried everything I can think of including: reinstalling and updating the various packages, restarting R Studio, updating my R and R Studio, rebooting, creating a simplified script (e.g. the one below), etc.
NOTE: if I run the 2 lines R code in a regular R script, it displays the map with no errors so I know the problem is probably not with leaflet.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "David Wilkes"
date: "March 30, 2017"
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown test for leaflet

```{r}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% addTiles %>% setView(lng = 5.0, lat = 51.0, zoom = 6)
```

pandoc.exe: Could not fetch E:\MYDOCU~1\R\R-33~1.3\library\leaflet\HTMLWI~1\lib\leaflet\#default#VML
E:\MYDOCU~1\R\R-33~1.3\library\leaflet\HTMLWI~1\lib\leaflet\: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS slides_test.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output slides_test.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "E:\MYDOCU~1\R\R-33~1.3\library\RMARKD~1\rmd\h\DEFAUL~1.HTM" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\ya1dwil1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQFfqPh\rmarkdown-str19f072517d2.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"' had status 67 
Execution halted
````

Answer (score 1):

It's really a pain.

I had the same issue. I updated my Pandoc and R. Now, it's working. Here is my session info:

> R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> Rcpp_0.12.14         knitr_1.18           magrittr_1.5
>   flexdashboard_0.5.1  xtable_1.8-2         lattice_0.20-35
>   R6_2.2.2
>
> stringr_1.2.0        tools_3.4.3          grid_3.4.3
>   htmltools_0.3.6      leafletplugins_0.0.1 crosstalk_1.0.0
>   yaml_2.1.16
>
> leaflet_1.1.0        rprojroot_1.3-2      digest_0.6.13
>   shiny_1.0.5          htmlwidgets_1.0      evaluate_0.10.1
>   mime_0.5
>
> rmarkdown_1.8        stringi_1.1.6        compiler_3.4.3
>   backports_1.1.2      jsonlite_1.5         httpuv_1.3.5

Hope it helps.